# Print node add form inside node.tpl.php

Tags: 7, forms

How can i print node/add form inside node.tpl.php?

Tried:

```
$form = node_add('nodetype');
print drupal_render($form);
```

But no success.

Comment: Have you considered to make your form a block?

Comment: i prefer to make it directly in node.tpl.php, so users can add referenced node right here.